# Replicating portfolios

Tags: finance, portfolio, finance-mathematics

Prices of a stock are modeled using a two-period binomial tree, with each period being six months.

The continuously compounded risk free interest rate is 7 %
The stock pays 2 % continuous dividend.
The current stock price is 65
The volatility of the stock is 40 %.
        Consider an American put option on the stock expiring in a year with a strike price of $65.

What is the number of stocks in the replicating portfolio at the end of the first 6 month period if we know the stock price decreased in the first period?

I was able to calculate the option premium. The formula I've been trying to use is e^(d*h)[(Cu-Cd)/(Su-Sd)]. However, I'm unsure if I need to do anything differently given that I'm trying to replicate the portfolio at the end of the first 6 month period. Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Without providing you with the full answer, here is a list of similar questions with detailed solutions, you will be able to see how this has been done and replicate it to produce the correct answer!

https://www.soa.org/files/edu/edu-2009-spring-exam-mfe-qa.pdf

Comment: Down-voted for being a link-only answer.

Comment: Cool!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!